# c++ char array null character while loop

Tags: c++, char

I have a function that keeps on incrementing the char, so it will display the next char in the ascci code, but my problem is it never breaks the loop

```
     char * myFunction (char* &text)
       {
               char *temp = (char *)malloc(strlen(text));
                char *tmp = temp;
                while(*tmp != '\0')
                 {
                          *tmp = *text++;  //im incrementing the text
                          tmp +=1;

                 }
          return temp;

        }

       char *text = "hello";
        cout<<myFunction(text)<<endl;
```

Comment: *tmp += 1;  ->  tmp += 1;

Comment: Better to use string functions like [strlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) (instead of `sizeof(text)`, which won't work, unless you want the size of the pointer itself) and [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) (instead of the manual loop). Also, don't assume that [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) is successful, _always_ check its return value (here `temp`)!

Comment: if `*text++` returns `'\0'` then *tmp +=1; will increament it

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It might be easier to throw all your code away and write something simpler.

Comment: increment to the next asci code of the char

Comment: @meWantToLearn, if you want to increment to the next ascii code of the char then since `'\0'` is also ascii char and if you are increamenting that then i think `while(*tmp != '\0')` will never be satisfied.

Comment: OK, I added some code that does that. I feel you are over-complicating things (or tag your question C, not C++.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are lots of problems in your code, I summarized them in comments below:

```
 // Making your argument char*& allows you to modify text variable from 
 // calling function, I dont think this was your intention. If you just 
 // want to pass string to this function change its type to `const char*`.
 // I dont think this return value you really want here, now you have char, but I 
 // suppose you want to return string, so it should be `char*` or `const 
 // char*`
 char myFunction (char* &text)
   { 
           // sizeof(text) will return 4bytes, which is size of pointer, 
           // you want strlen(text)+1 here to get length of string + 1 
           // char for zero (end of string)
           char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(text));
            char *tmp = temp;

            // You should dereference *tmp, but tmp is uninitialized here, 
            // I think you want to use *text here.
            while(tmp != '\0')
             {
                      *tmp = *text++;  //im incrementing the text

                      // You are incrementing value pointed by tmp, 
                      // if you want to increment tmp to next string 
                      // element use tmp++;
                      *tmp +=1;

             }

             // Here assign zero to last element of text            

      // temp is char* and your return value is char, this is wrong, 
      // you should change return value of myFunction to char*. Also 
      // remember to call free() on returned string once its no
      // longer needed - otherwise you will introduce memory leaks
      return temp;

    }




   // This should be `const char *text = "hello";` In c++ string
   // literals are of type `const char*`
   char *text = "hello";
    cout<<myFunction(text)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while(tmp != '\0')
```

to be

```
while(*tmp != '\0')
```

`tmp` is the address of the start of the string which will never be `'\0'`

Comment: Still, I cannot see how they expect to find a `'\0'` in there. That and all the other bugs.